# Android Studio drawer menu preview issue

Tags: android, android-studio, menu

I am unable to preview the menu in android studio.

I am already adding `tools:showIn="navigation_view"` to the file but still not working.

*Screenshot*

[image: Screenshot]

*build.gradle :*

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

*menu :*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  tools:showIn="navigation_view">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_dashboard"
            android:title="Dashboard"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_dashboard"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_profile"
            android:title="Profile"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_dashboard"/>
    </group>
</menu>
```

Comment: invalidate and restart android studio

Comment: What is invalidate? Is it means View.invalidate?
I had tried to restart but still not working.

Comment: in android studio, go to File-> then select (invalidate and restart) -> select first option

Comment: if this dont help then clean your project

Comment: It still same after invalidate.

Comment: whats ur android studio version?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, i just going to ignore this problem as this will not heavily impact my project, i just need to run the program to see the side bar. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: no problem. You welcome :)